# How to load a local JSON file server-side at runtime

Tags: astrojs

I wonder if it is possible (and eventually how) to load a local JSON (or other formats) data file server-side (SSR, no AJAX) at runtime.

The use case is that I want to be able to inject a configuration file when I start my Astro site (post-build) and have it loaded server-side (SSR), to be able to inject some runtime configuration values avoiding the unnecessary AJAX burden.

The main issue I have encountered in my attempts is that all the files I have been able to load locally had passed through the build process (in an SSG fashion). I need the data file to be untouched by the build because the file name must be predictable, thus injectable.

Answer (score 0):

Astro does a passthrough copy of any files in your `public/` directory directly to the build output, so perhaps that will do what you want?

For example, a project with a `public/config.json` file will output the same JSON, unprocessed to `dist/config.json` (assuming you haven’t set a custom build output directory with the `outDir` option).

Comment: ok, but then how do I load it during server-side rendering at runtime? I tried something like `fetch('/config.json')` in the _frontmatter_, but it complains that it's not a well-formatted URL...

Comment: You might be able to `import config from '../public/config.json'`? In theory a JSON import should be supported.

Comment: Doing it via `import` will make it load at build time, which would defeat the whole purpose of the question as it will not load updates injected at bootstrap/runtime.